# Custom labels used in LWC cached/disappearing in the Community on relogin

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, lightning-experience

All, our team is facing an issue where custom label values seem to be cached when used in lwc community.

Reproduce

1. Login into community, open the LWC built which has custom label - values appear looks good.
2. Logout
3. Login back to community, open the LWC built which has custom label - values disappear.

Temp fix which fixed the issue was deselecting the checkbox for “Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance”.

Has anyone faced a similar issue, we are accessing custom labels as provided here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_labels

Comment: I frequently have issues **during development** (and typically on scratch orgs, but also on dev orgs and sandboxes) due to the extreme caching applied when that session management setting is checked and you are still making changes to elements of the UI (such as page layouts etc., but I guess also custom labels). I haven't seen this issue in a production org. That said, since you are invalidating the session and logging in again you really *shouldn't* seen this problem even with that setting checked. Could be a platform bug...